# Simple Form behaving different than form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simple_form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@book, wrapper: :horizontal_form, wrapper_mappings: {
  }, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="image-upload">
    <%= f.input :book_cover, as: :file , input_html: { class: 'fa fa-cloud-download'}%>
  </div>
    <%= f.input :category_id, collection: @categories, prompt: 'Select a category' %>
    <%= f.input :author %>
    <%= f.input :description %>

  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
      <%= f.button :cancel, to: books_path %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my simple_form form. I want the f.input :book_cover to be displayed as the icon fa fa-cloud-download without the normal download button.

CSS.

```
.image-upload > input {
    display: none;
}
```

Ive got another form working with it (this is just a snippet of a regular form_for resource:

```
 <%= f.form_group :avatar, class: "row" do |f| %>
                  <%= f.label :avatar, class: "col-sm-4 col-form-label" %>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label class="image-upload form-control">
                      <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
                      <% if @user.avatar.present? %> <%= @user.avatar_file_name %>
                      <% end %>
                      <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
                      <%= f.error_messages %>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
```

Can't seem to get my simple_form working with just the icon.

Edit: Uploading a image to show what my problem is and what it should look like

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO9Wb.png)
[should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EVDU.png)

Comment: What do you mean by _can't seem to get working_? What happens? Is there an error? What does the error message say? How did you try it - please show the simple_form code with the icon.

Comment: sorry, updated my question with some images to show what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleForm has a `input_field` method that you can use instead `input` to render only the actual input element, without wrapper div and label. That helps if you want to build more complex structures manually.

```
<label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Book cover</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <label class="image-upload form-control">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
    <%= f.input_field :book_cover %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried that but without success. The regular choose file button still gets displayed. Also tried out input_field without success either.

Comment: @flenning12 Updated answer, hope that helps. HTML structure will probably need further work to fit better in layout.

Comment: Ayy thanks for that! Managed to play around with the HTML structure and got it working now. I feel like the simple_form documentation is a bit strange.